# Keyboard Problem with Debian testing and gdm3

Tags: debian, xorg, keyboard

I'm driving a Debian testing machine that is running fine. But since testing includes Linux Kernel 3 I have the following problem:

While booting all is working (I mean especially the keyboard) - controlled by switching `NumLock` state. The moment gdm3 starts (from init) the keyboard dies... It can only be reanimated by killing gdm3 (I do this via **`ssh`**). Running `startx` from console behaves fine, thus the "`xorg.conf`" seems to be fine.

The output from `startx` reads as

```
X.Org X Server 1.10.3
Release Date: 2011-07-08
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.0.0-rc6-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux sobolev 3.0.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 24 02:24:44 UTC 2011 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-1-amd64 root=UUID=7d005ab3-c823-4cc9-b70a-9316a5eab8d6 ro quiet
Build Date: 07 August 2011  06:45:11PM
xorg-server 2:1.10.3-1 (Cyril Brulebois <kibi@debian.org>)
Current version of pixman: 0.22.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Aug 26 09:19:48 2011
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
```

Any ideas? I'm using a PS/2 keyboard and USB mouse. The mouse is alive under gdm3.

Comment: I'm curious about how do you kill `gdm3` without a working keyboard.

Comment: @enzotib Login via ssh is working fine... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens typically when you upgrade your `Xorg` server without upgrading/re-installing the xorg keyboard drivers afterwards. This is contained in a separate package - on Gentoo it is `xf86-input-keyboard`, on Debian *(according to Gilles' comment below)* the name should be **`xserver-xorg-input-kbd`** . Try upgrading/re-installing it.

<sub>**Edit** : Merged the package name information from Gilles' comment.</sub>

Comment: On Debian squeeze, the package name is `xserver-xorg-input-kbd`, and `-mouse` for the mouse.

Comment: @Gilles and rozcietrzewiacz: Thanks for those details. I found those packages, too - and installed them - but that solved not my problem... Any further ideas?

Comment: Oh, so the startx works fine... Then gdm is probably broken :/ But first try to boot the same system with an older kernel (since you mention the kernel upgrade).

Comment: Hi - the problem is solved. After reinstalling `gdm3`, `x-server-xorg` und the `xserver-xort-input-*` drivers, the problems remained. I tried logging in with screen-keyboard and found the last option `Only accept long keystrokes (keyboard lag)` (in menu for disabled users) activated. Disabling of course did it. Thanks for all help!