# Keyboard doesn't work at graphical login

Tags: debian, xorg, keyboard, display-manager

After an update, my laptop keyboard doesn't work anymore when I want to login (while the touchpad does). This is true whatever the display manager used (xdm, lightdm). I can't even switch to console with ctrl+alt+F1. 
Note the keyboard works when I boot in recovery mode so the problem is related to xorg-*

I tried to reinstall xserver-xorg-input-kbd|evdev without result.

I am running under Debian sid. During the update the following packages related to the keyboard have changed: ***keyboard-configuration, console-setup, keyutils***

Several questions seem related but none solved this issue:

[Problem with keyboard and mouse in gdm3 and lightdm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/problem-with-keyboard-and-mouse-in-gdm3-and-lightdm)

[Keyboard Problem with Debian testing and gdm3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/keyboard-problem-with-debian-testing-and-gdm3)

[Keyboard and mouse do not function in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38747/keyboard-and-mouse-do-not-function-in-debian)

---

I fully reinstalled xorg which did not solve the problem ...
The best I could do until now is to use a virtual keyboard ...

Comment: The Debian Wiki does say "Should I use sid on my desktop?
If you think you can handle a broken Debian system, sure. Do you know what to do if libpam0g breaks, preventing all logins? Do you know what to do if grub breaks, causing the boot process to hang forever? These things have happened. They will happen again.

If you'd like to avoid the brown-paper-bag bugs like these, then use testing instead."

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did not find the reason for the problem but I found a solution : update the kernel